# express-jwt - Error: secret should be set

Tags: node.js, docker, jwt, nodemon

i am trying to deploy the "Lite Farm"(https://github.com/LiteFarmOrg/LiteFarm) an open source farm management application, i followed the guide of the docker deployment everything went good but then it throw an error of the "secret should be set"

[image: docker representation of the project/container]

[image: Error i am getting by executing "docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up"]

besides i am providing JWT-Secret key  in .env file but there is a "js" file "generatekeypair.js" i tried generating the key by that file and add to the JWT-SECRET in .env file.
B

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you haven't already, I suggest reading the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. In particular, it is best to paste code and error output as text, and if not possible, as an embedded (not linked) image.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are getting this error since you are missing some critical configuration required by the container you are trying to launch.

As can be seen in the [LiteFarm docker-compose instructions](https://github.com/LiteFarmOrg/LiteFarm#using-docker-compose), they recommend using an `.env` file with specific environment variables, including `JWT_SECRET`.

You can either use an `.env` file, or set them directly in the `docker-compose` file (without exposing the secret itself).

See the [Environment variables in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) guide.